# Error When Using Application Initialization in IIS 8

Tags: iis-8, preloading

We are migrating our existing web applications from Server 2008 with IIS 7 to Server 2012 with IIS 8.  When I set "Preload Enabled" to true the app pool serving the process immediately crashes with the below error.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          7/30/2013 2:20:48 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      513582-API1
Description:
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x5010ac20
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000128d
Faulting process id: 0x2520
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce8d5179cc6403
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: c18a3c6d-f944-11e2-93f8-bc305bf8e042
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-07-30T18:20:48.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>52432</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>513582-API1</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>8.0.9200.16384</Data>
    <Data>50108835</Data>
    <Data>msvcrt.dll</Data>
    <Data>7.0.9200.16384</Data>
    <Data>5010ac20</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>000000000000128d</Data>
    <Data>2520</Data>
    <Data>01ce8d5179cc6403</Data>
    <Data>c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll</Data>
    <Data>c18a3c6d-f944-11e2-93f8-bc305bf8e042</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have this in the system.webserver node of my web.config:

```
<applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="In_LoadBalancer_Rotation.html" skipManagedModules="true" >
        <add initializationPage="/Default.aspx" />
 </applicationInitialization>
```

I also have the app pool for the application set to "AlwaysRunning".

As soon as I comment out the above section in the web.config and set "Preload Enabled" to false everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

We use Helicon's ISAPI_Rewrite to get Apache style htaccess rewrites in IIS.  I updated to the latest version and the issue is resolved.